# Remove duplicate key in a multimap

Tags: c++, stl, key, duplicates, multimap

I have a multimap:

```
std::multimap < string, string >::iterator iter_map;
multimap < string, set<string> > my.map;  

Typical output and data structure:

key        -    value

bird       -    air
bird       -    earth
fish       -    water
lion       -    earth
lion       -    water
```

I would like change the data structure (no only print to) such that that the new data
would be:

```
bird      -    air, earth
fish      -    water
lion      -    earth, water
```

In other way, how to eliminate the duplicate keys?

I did this:

```
int size_mmap = namesMultiMap1.size();
pair<multimap<string,string>::iterator,multimap<string,string>::iterator> ret;

for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++){

   cout << " xxx "<< " =>";
   ret = namesMultiMap1.equal_range("xxx");

     for (nameItr1=ret.first; nameItr1!=ret.second; ++nameItr1)
     cout << " " << (*nameItr1).second;
```

}

In this way I print the values associeted at a key xxx but I print a element at once.
I would like to print all keys and values. I need automated this because the map is big.
If I iterate using a iterator for namesMultiMap1 a print the repeat keys.

Comment: My guess was iterate on the my.map->first, comparing the equals keys, and for the same keys put the value in a set of set. But at the moment this didn´t work.

Comment: Show the code and we'll see what's wrong

Comment: Please the edit code at top.

Comment: The question's title implies you want to remove elements from a data structure, but the question's text is about formatting a data structure as readable text in a specific way. Maybe you should reconsider the title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, this can be done like follows. Notice, that the type of the result is `map<string, set<string> >`, not `multimap < string, set<string> >` as you wanted, cause you don't want duplicated keys in it, so `map` makes more sense.

```
#include <map>
#include <set>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>

using namespace std;

typedef multimap<string,string> mm; 
typedef map<string, set<string> > ms; 

ms convert(const mm& m)
{   
    ms r;

    for (mm::const_iterator it = m.begin(); it != m.end(); ++it)
    {   
        set<string>& s(r[it->first]);
        s.insert(it->second);
    }   

    return r;
}   


int main()
{   
    mm m;
    m.insert(make_pair("john", "kowalski"));
    m.insert(make_pair("john", "smiths"));
    m.insert(make_pair("mary", "doe"));
    m.insert(make_pair("mary", "walker"));

    ms s(convert(m));

    for (ms::iterator it = s.begin(); it != s.end(); ++it)
    {   
        cout << it->first << ": ";
        set<string> &st(it->second);
        copy(st.begin(), st.end(), ostream_iterator<string>(cout, ", "));
        cout << endl;
    }   
    return 0;
}
```

This will print:

```
john: kowalski, smiths,
mary: doe, walker,
```

Comment: You are welcome. I would appreciate it if you could close the question - only if it solves your problem, of course.

Comment: Sorry piokuc, but how a I close the question?

Comment: @@user1871217 you just need to mark an answer as correct. the big 'tick' sign on the side of the answer must be green.